# Two Route attributes for class and it's method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, routes

I have a web API in vs 2015. Since my UI project is separated, I have define this attributes before the controller class:

```
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class myController : Controller
    {  
       ...
```

In this controller I have a method that would insert some data came from client  side HTTP request. I want to name it "Add" (and not "Post"). I want to call this method in `post` request. So I Added the `[HttpPost]` as below:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public object Add(string title, string myStruct)
    {
```

How can I determine that this is my Post method?
Should I use `[Route("api/[controller]/define")]` before method definition?!
Can I set the routing as from this state forward?
 My URL is

```
http://localhost:54848/#/myController/define
```

Comment: I truly do not understand. Can you clarify what is your actual problem and what you want to achieve? Also, why are you showing a client-related URI in your question (why the hash inside the URI if your problem is with Web API)?

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I determine this is my pot method?" Also, you cannot have a `#` in a URL. Well, you can have one, but it won't get passed to your code.

Comment: that is the url in browser and i'm using angularJS so I have #.  I want to have a customized method name, and won't to use the Post or other name prefixed by Post. So, at first I added the [HttpPost], but i have to define the acceptable routing too. Then I don't know should I set the acceptable rout from the beginning or not (since I have mentioned that one level upper, before the class)

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear, I will try to answer from whatever I understood.
You should be adding route attribute in your controller's method like this :

```
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
[Route("api/exampleController")]
public class exampleController : Controller
{  
   ...

 [HttpPost]
 [Route("add")]
 public object Add(string title, string myStruct)
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

The url for api call should then be something like this : `http://www.example.com/api/exampleController/add`

The url which you posted in your question looks like a routing url in angular you should be doing that from $stateproviders :

```
  $stateProvider.state('define', {
        url: '/define',
        templateUrl: 'page-posts-list.html',
        controller: mycontroller
    });
```

you can then call your api's post method with the url above from my controller's factory. Hope this should help you.

Comment: I think exactly you understood the question correctly. But I did as you told but I have access denied! (Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: You will need to enable CORS in your api. In your package manager console type "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" . Add config.EnableCors(); in Register() method before config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...);  of WebApiConfig.cs class. Add attribute [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] in public class exampleController : Controller
{  ....} and try once.

Comment: I have enabled that at the beginning (for the class). It doesn't enough?

Comment: Please remove that and try with steps I provided. See here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Comment: As I mentioned in question  I use  vs 2015. As you know, it App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs doesn't exist here, right? Also I have done that in startup.cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113211/discussion-between-pushpendra-and-elnaz).

Comment: According to @Pushpendra's comment, I added     AddCors(options     =>     options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>
                {
                    p.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    p.AllowAnyHeader();
                    p.AllowAnyMethod();
                })); to my middle wares in Startup.cs  (in vs 2015 and not before) and it works